# import error: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, dataset, artificial-intelligence

When I try to import the beginning of this code I am faced with this error:

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.

My code is:

```
# Basic Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image

# Imports for Building CNN
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img

# Ignore Warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

The error (from jupyter notebook) appeared as:

> ### ``
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [5], in <cell line: 3>()
> 1 # Basic Imports
> 2 import numpy as np
> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> 4 from glob import glob
> 5 from PIL import Image
>
> File D:\Black\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py:109, in 
> 105 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
> 107 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
> 108 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
> 109 from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
> 110 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
> 111 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated
>
> File D:\Black\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py:27, in 
> 25 from matplotlib import _api, cbook
> 26 from matplotlib.cbook import ls_mapper
> 27 from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
> 28 from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
> 29 from matplotlib._enums import JoinStyle, CapStyle
>
> File D:\Black\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:51, in 
> 49 from numbers import Number
> 50 import re
> 51 from PIL import Image
> 52 from PIL.PngImagePlugin import PngInfo
> 54 import matplotlib as mpl
>
> File D:\Black\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:100, in 
> 91 MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = int(1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 4 // 3)
> 94 try:
> 95     # If the _imaging C module is not present, Pillow will not load.
> 96     # Note that other modules should not refer to _imaging directly;
> 97     # import Image and use the Image.core variable instead.
> 98     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
> 99     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
> 100     from . import _imaging as core
> 102     if **version** != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):
> 103         raise ImportError(
> 104             "The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:\n"
> 105             f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
> 106             f"Pillow version: {**version**}"
> 107         )
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
> ``

I think something is outdated? if that is the case, what can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be some problem with conda installing it.
It worked for me when I tried with pip instead `pip install --force pillow`.