# Matplotlib cannot find the installed PIL module

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I want to print `rcParams` to see the settings during stages of my program.

Here are my imports:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import rcParams
```

I've tried the following:

`print(mpl.rcParamsDefault)`,`print(mpl.rcParams)` and `print(rcParams)`

I get the same error message for all three:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Minitab_Killer\rcParams_print_out.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as mpl
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, animation, cbook
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 34, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 103, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
```

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43264773/3225420), some resolve this by fixing their `pillow` installation. I am using `anaconda` so I ran the `conda install -c anaconda pillow` command and it updated `pillow` but the error message did not change.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75601334/3225420) and ran `pip install --force pillow`, same error message.

While I tried the `pip` answer I desire a pure `conda` solution.

From `conda list` here are the relevant packages:
`python 3.10.9`,`pillow 9.4.0`,`matplotlib 3.5.3`.

Update:

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75601334/3225420) :`pip install --force pillow`, and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/z1ur40/pillow_importerror_dll_load_failed_while/): `Pillow 9.0.0` getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Minitab_Killer\rcParams_print_out.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib import rcParams 
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, animation, cbook
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 34, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\D\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 103, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
```

What should I try next?

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install/remove packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: Title and question changed (improved) based on comments.  I desire to have `conda`  manage dependencies, tried `pip` as option of last (known) resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a bug report on GitHub [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7494).

Turns out this was not a bug.  Andrew Murray offered multiple things to try for resolution, in my case `conda upgrade conda` solved my problem.