# Importerror for spacypdfreader

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy, importerror

All of a sudden my code doesn't work anymore since the error like in the title pops-up. It happens when running the following code:

```
from spacypdfreader.spacypdfreader import pdf_reader
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell 2 line 1
      9 import spacy
---> 10 from spacypdfreader.spacypdfreader import pdf_reader

      1 import importlib.metadata
----> 3 from spacypdfreader.spacypdfreader import pdf_reader
      5 __version__ = importlib.metadata.version("spacypdfreader")

     10 from ._utils import _filter_doc_by_page, _get_number_of_pages
     11 from .console import console
---> 12 from .parsers import pdfminer, pytesseract
     14 # Set up the spacy custom extensions.
     16 if not Token.has_extension("page_number"):

      1 import tempfile
      2 from pathlib import Path
----> 4 from pdf2image import convert_from_path
      5 from PIL import Image
...
     87             f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
     88             f"Pillow version: {__version__}"
     89         )
```

With the error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
```

Then I tried to run the following code like discussed here [import error: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74352151/import-error-dll-load-failed-while-importing-imaging-the-specified-module-cou):

```
pip install --force pillow
```

Returns:

```
ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 10.1.0
Pillow version: 10.0.1
```

I tried using both version of `pillow`, but the error remains the same. I don't understand why this error happens and how this fix it. So I was wondering if anyone know how to solve this problem?

---

I'm using the following python version:

```
python --version
Python 3.10.12
```

Here are the python packages versions using `conda list`:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pdf2image                 1.16.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pdfminer-six              20211012                 pypi_0    pypi
pdfreader                 0.1.12                   pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    10.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi    
pip                       23.3.1                   pypi_0    pypi
spacy                     3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
spacy-legacy              3.0.12          py310haa95532_0
spacy-loggers             1.0.4           py310haa95532_0
spacypdfreader            0.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: This looks like the mixong of conda and pip might be an issue. Is this in the anaconda base env, or in an env that you have created fresh. If the latter, then the commands you used to create the env can be useful